How to use username/password saved for a different domain when authenticating in git push usong HTTPS?
Use case
I actually just want to clone and edit aka push to a GitHub Gist locally. GitHub now offers a UI and actually even a doc for cloning gists as they are usual repos.
So you can just get the URL from that button – or – really, AFAIK you can also just use the URL of the gist itself from the address bar:

This works flawlessly.
However, when I push I get the usual username/password prompt?
$ git push         
Username for 'https://gist.github.com': 

Problem
I already have my credentials for GitHub(.com) (or better: https://github.com) authentication saved, so I don't like entering them again. After all, I am, already authenticated for GitHub, like many of you likely are… (but I rarely push to a gist)
For two reasons:

with 2FA, I probably need to generate a new token having two different tokens for the device, just because of a slightly different remote host (URL)
or locally extract it from by (possibly secure) credential store…

In both cases, when the token(s) expire(s), I would have to renew both tokens, respectively have to renew the same time twice. Given there is a time difference between renewing and I also not always push to GitHub Gists (rather rarely), it is annoying when I forget to renew all of these and then suddenly always need to fix aka renew them when I later push to a gist…
Solutions

Yes I know this is expected and obviously I could just enter my GitHub credentials or – as hopefully all use 2FA by now, some GitHub Token generated for the device etc. As explained above, this causes some inconveniences though as I now duplicate credentials for the same service.
Yes I know I could switch to SSH instead and authenticate with that, which also allows pushing to git@github.com:5834862.git which would use the GitHub.com domain.

Wanted
I would like a solution, where I can tell git/the credential helper or whatever is responsible at that point, to use **the same credentials for https://gist.github.com as for https://github.com.
I guess only because of this subdomain, it "breaks" the authentication and git thinks I am not already logged in.
Solutions tried
I tried somehow setting a pushInsteadOf or insteadOf, as such in .gitconfig:
# DOES NOT WORK
[url "https://github.com"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://gist.github.com

But that would just result in a weird URL it could not push to:
$ git push               
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ac09b28bc9de833e772cb1509364b421.git/' not found

Also I tried finding out whether there maybe is a git configuration option like useCredentialsFor or so, but my shell autocompletion at least did not offer anything:
$ git config credential.https://gist.github.com.<tab>
helper       -- external helper to be called when a username or password credential is needed
*            -- unknown option name
useHttpPath  -- whether or not to consider the "path" component of an http or https URL to be important
username     -- if no username is set use this username by default

